# 'Would take thousands of years' or 'Will take thousands of years'

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Watching a video clip of youtube channel "In a netshell – Kurzgesagt", I came to have a question on the following sentence in the video.

> With our current technology, sending a human to the closest star would take thousands of years.

Obviously, it is a plain sentence. But the question is, can't it be written as the following sentence? (in which "would" is replaced by "will")

> With our current technology, sending a human to the closest star will take thousands of years.

I guess there are subtle differences in nuance of them, but I can't see it clearly. Can anyone explain them?

Answer (score 2):

The word *would* here is the conditional form that we use to discuss hypotheticals.

> I **would** take the metro  but I do not have the money.

With the future tense *will*, your expressing a definite possibility.

> I **will** take the metro

That's the nuance between them.

Comment: Using *will* in the sentence of Alcan Kim   is not wrong. It is simply represents a real conditional without the *if-clause*.

Comment: *Would* is not subjunctive. It is a modal verb, just as are  *will, can, might, could, may, must, etc*. It's true *would* is often used to talk about unreal conditions, but this does mean it is subjunctive. Please produce a reputable source that says *would* is subjunctive.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Sorry, I tried to fix my answer. It's definitely not a subjeftive...

Comment: @RobertTilman Oh, I see some point. Let me take an example. If a captain in a spaceship getting wrecked commanded his crews escape from it, they would say "we are trying to reach the nearest star. But it *will* take at least 3 hours with our technology". Using "will" in that case could be more natural than "would", since it expresses a definite possibility they are going to have, right? In other hands, "Reaching Alpha Centauri from here *would* take only a minutes, is it alright to leave for there, captain?" would be the counterpart, i think.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying to say. However my answer was a little bit wromg. You can find a better explanation here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm as they explain the levels of probability thing that I didn't think about.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences are conditional sentences without the *if-clause* (protasis) explicitly stated.  The *if clause* is implicit.

You can consider the two sentences as equivalent to the following forms, which explicitly state the protasis (*if-clause*):

> With our current technology, sending a human to the closest star would take thousands of years, if we chose to do it.

This is an unreal conditional. It talks about something we are, in fact,   not actually going to do.

> With our current technology, sending a human to the closest star will take thousands of years, if we choose to do it.

This is a real conditional. It talks about something that is possible to do.

Answer (score -1):

The 'would' is emphasised here on the duration (thousand of years). And the difference or nuance you are talking about between 'would' and 'will' is the amount of possibility. 'Will' is definite while "would' is indefinite. So the speaker is not sure that how long it will exactly take to send someone to the closest star. That is why he used "would" as a approximity. "Will" will land you in the stars in thousand years for sure :)